# Remove leading digits from a string

Tags: string, powershell

How can I remove all the digits from the start of a string.

Before:

```
234234adsf3fs3fs34
```

After:

```
adsf3fs3fs34
```

The `.TrimLeft()` function doesn't seem to accept regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use -Replace, which does accept RegEx:

```
"234234adsf3fs3fs34" -replace "^[0-9]*"
```

That will result in your desired output.

Alternatively you can use the .TrimStart() method as such:

```
("234234adsf3fs3fs34").TrimStart("0123456789")
```

That will also output what you want. It looks for anything contained within the () to remove, but is not RegEx friendly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this statement:

```
string.TrimStart("1234567890")
```

Hope that helps!